# Responsive Right-click Image Protection

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

Right-click and save is probably one of the most common ways that people lift images from websites. Although there is no real solution to stopping image theft and the best way is to watermark images, sometimes, its worth implementing as many protection methods as possible, thus making it more difficult for common image lifting.

I use a transparent gif method to prevent visitors who right to right click and same images on a website. The setup is like so:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><!--some irrelevant stuff--></td>
<td style="background: url(http://www.urltotherealimage.com) no-repeat center center"><a href="http://www.somelink.com"><img src="trans.gif" style="height:100%;width:100%;"/></a></td>
<td><!--some irrelevant stuff--></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm not looking to make this protection responsive. However, the whole background image setup is proving to be difficult considering I need to support all the way to IE8 as well as all other modern browsers and mobile device browsers.

So, I'm asking if anyone knows a good approach to keep this type of masking protection in a responsive format compatible with IE8.

I have found a solution, see my answer below.

Comment: You do know that this is not preventing people from downloading your images, right?

Comment: You can't protect the images. I can just open up Chrome's developer tools, click on Resources -> Images and see the direct links to all of the images that your site loads.

Comment: There are other ways to get your image. The user can follow the url path and retrieve your image by just looking in their web console.

Comment: What's the point to do this ? Do you really think people won't inspect the html or take a screenshot if they are really interested ?

Comment: I am totally aware of this. However, this is probably the most common amatuer way of saving photos to be uploading on social sites. Believe it or not, not everyone knows how to read HTML code who wants to save an image to their hard drive. Any many of them aren't aware of the print screen button. I'm not trying to combat those who know, i'm combating those who don't know much. This, along with disabling right click and watermark options sure cover almost every possibility.

Comment: Watermarking is the most effective way to prevent image theft.

Comment: Please provide code to your current responsive table, the one without a link properly covering the whole cell

Comment: @FelipeAls I don't have a responsive table yet as this problem is preventing me from doing so. But I would eventually turn the TDs into block elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me educate:

1. Set the surrounding TD style="positon:relative;overflow:hidden;"
2. Create an img of the trans gif with style="position:absolute;width:100%;max-height:100%;"
3. add your other image with style="max-width:100%;"

Job done.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for responsive tables:

try here: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Another suggestion is to add a watermark to your images. You can also do this on the fly using PHP to save you from having to manually change them.

http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/